# SQL Server : update columns with sum() and group by on a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update the SQL Server table where my estimatename, region, marketname, b_date, len, creative, file_id are same and sum the spend column to make it single row.

For example:

**mdl_drtv_part_b_master_id**:

```
ESTIMATE NAME   REGION  MARKET NAME BCAST DATE  LEN CREATIVE    SPEND   file_id create_date
451 4Q18 EAST CENTRAL   EC  PIT PA  2018-11-15  60  GET MORE - HYBRID   410.00  5862    2019-04-05 16:17:14.453
452 4Q18 EAST CENTRAL   EC  PIT PA  2018-11-15  60  Get More - Hybrid   350.00  5862    2019-04-05 16:17:14.453
1929    4Q18 EAST CENTRAL   EC  PIT PA  2018-11-15  60  GET MORE - HYBRID   646.00  5863    2019-04-05 16:18:51.490
```

I would like to get this as my output:

```
ESTIMATE NAME   REGION  MARKET NAME BCAST DATE  LEN CREATIVE            SPEND   file_ID create_date
4Q18 EAST CENTRAL   EC  PIT PA  2018-11-15  60  GET MORE - HYBRID   760.00  5862    2019-04-05 16:17:14.453
4Q18 EAST CENTRAL   EC  PIT PA  2018-11-15  60  GET MORE - HYBRID   646.00  5863    2019-04-05 16:18:51.490
```

Here is my SQL select to get my output results:

```
SELECT 
    [ESTIMATE NAME], [REGION], [MARKET NAME], [BCAST DATE], [LEN],  
    [CREATIVE], SUM(SPEND), file_ID, [create_date]
FROM  
    dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl
WHERE
    [bcast date] = '2018-11-15'
    -- AND region LIKE 'ec%'
    AND creative = 'GET MORE - HYBRID'
GROUP BY 
    [ESTIMATE NAME], [REGION], [MARKET NAME], [BCAST DATE], [LEN],
    [CREATIVE], file_ID, [create_date]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your sql `select` seems to give you your desired output, what else do you need?

Comment: I need the update statement .

Comment: Do you want to set the `SPEND` column of each record to the `sum` of `SPEND` of its group?

Comment: yes you are correct. I want to sum the SPEND column by its file_id when the estimatename , region , marketname, bcast_date,len_creative are same.
For the above example i have 2 records with file_id = 5862 
I would like sum those 2 rows and make it one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
update dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl
set SPEND = 
(
select sum(SPEND)
from dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl mdp
where
mdp.[ESTIMATE NAME]= dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl.[ESTIMATE NAME]
and
mdp.[REGION]= dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl.[REGION]
and
mdp.[MARKET NAME]= dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl.[MARKET NAME]
and
mdp.[BCAST DATE]= dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl.[BCAST DATE]
and
mdp.[BCAST DATE]= dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl.[BCAST DATE]
and
mdp.[LEN]= dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl.[LEN]
and
mdp.[CREATIVE]= dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl.[CREATIVE]
and
mdp.[CREATIVE]= dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl.[CREATIVE]
and
mdp.[file_ID,]= dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl.[file_ID,]
and
mdp.[create_date]= dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl.[create_date]
)
```

Then after updating the `SPEND` column, you can remove duplicates by using a window function:

```
;with cte as (
  select row_number() over (partition by [ESTIMATE NAME] ,[REGION], [MARKET NAME] , [BCAST DATE],[LEN],[CREATIVE] ,[file_ID],[create_date] order by [ESTIMATE NAME] desc) rn
  FROM dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl)
delete from cte where rn> 1
```

Comment: I tried your the query you provided and i see it doing sum on the SPEND column but i still see  3 records instead of 2 records
451 4Q18 EAST CENTRAL EC PIT PA 2018-11-15 60 GET MORE - HYBRID 760.00 5862 2019-04-06 04:30:02.623
452 4Q18 EAST CENTRAL EC PIT PA 2018-11-15 60 Get More - Hybrid 760.00 5862 2019-04-06 04:30:02.623
1929 4Q18 EAST CENTRAL EC PIT PA 2018-11-15 60 GET MORE - HYBRID 646.00 5863 2019-04-06 04:31:32.163

Once the sum is updated i would like to delete where mdl_drtv_part_b_master_id
= 452 so i won't have duplicate records in the table.

Comment: @swathi Now I got your point, answer was updated. See if it's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a UPDATE with join on a subquery based on your select

```
update  your_table  
SET m.SPEND = t.sum_spend
FROM your_table m 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT [ESTIMATE NAME] ,[REGION], [MARKET NAME] 
      , [BCAST DATE],[LEN],[CREATIVE]
      ,  SUM(SPEND) sum_spend , file_ID,[create_date]
  FROM  dbo.mdl_drtv_part_b_sl
  where  [bcast date] = '2018-11-15'
  --and region like 'ec%'
  and creative = 'GET MORE - HYBRID'
  GROUP   BY [ESTIMATE NAME] ,[REGION], [MARKET NAME] , [BCAST DATE],[LEN],[CREATIVE],  file_ID,[create_date]
) t ON t.[ESTIMATE NAME] = m.[ESTIMATE NAME]
      AND t.[REGION] = m.[REGION]
      AND t.[MARKET NAME]  = m.[MARKET NAME] 
      AND t.[BCAST DATE] ) m.[BCAST DATE] 
      AND t.[LEN] = m.[LEN]
      AND t.[CREATIVE] = m.[CREATIVE]
      AND t.file_ID = m.file_ID
      AND t.[create_date] = m.[create_date]
```